# Tomcat 9 Thread issue - how to increase TPS in tomcat

Tags: performance, tomcat, tps

Tomcat TPS is low

loaded test done with 100000 threads per second, getting 1200 TPS
how to increase TPS.

We have Tomcat 9.0.78 installed on RHEL 9 server with 16 Core + 64 GB RAM

Below are the configuration parameters done on servers

### server.xml

maxThreads="10000" minSpareThreads="4000" maxConnections="100000"

**HHD harddisk**

### OS config

ulimit and Soft Limits set to unlimited